# Game timer won't stop

Tags: java, swing, timer, jframe

I am trying to set a timer to randomly set the frame in the screen, but then, depending on the `boolean`, set it back to normal.  I have already tried `.cancel()` but it doesn't work.  How could I stop this timer?:

```
if(e.getSource()==impossible){

            impossiblity=!impossiblity;
            System.out.println(impossiblity);
            if(!impossiblity){
                new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    public void run()  {
                        int randWidth=(int)((dim.width-gameFrame.getSize().width) * Math.random());
                        int randHeight=(int)((dim.height-gameFrame.getSize().height) * Math.random());
                        gameFrame.setLocation(randWidth, randHeight);//sets location to center
                    }
                }, 1000, 1000);
            } else gameFrame.setLocation(dim.width/2-gameFrame.getSize().width/2, 0);//sets Location to center of screen
        }
```

right now it does set the gameframe back to normal but then goes right back to randomizing

Comment: For starters, you have two booleans which appear to come out of nowhere - `impossible` and `impossibility`...

Comment: sorry i didn't include that

Comment: Better to use a Swing `Timer` for (almost) anything to do with a GUI.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You're using a Third parameter `1000` ms for REPETITION: `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)`. 2 Parameters are usually used if you don't want the timer to repeat. `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`

Comment: *"I am trying to set a timer to randomly set the frame in the screen"*  It sounds incredibly irritating.  I'm just saying...

Comment: Why not `javax.swing.Timer`?

Comment: how could i used javax.swing.Timer

Answer (score 0):

In general trying to cancel timers or other threads from outside the thread is a bad idea and leads to all sorts of problems.

Your best bet is to set some sort of flag or counter that the TimerTask checks when it comes to run.